# Load a second app in background and launch behind a loading screen

Tags: unity, c#, android, launcher

there is a way to preload an application in android from Unity? I mean.. I'm developing a launcher and every click in icon, should be launch a different game.. so, the time between show a loading animation and open the second app, in android, It's posible to make..  when the loading's animation is fadeout and behind the loading screen, the second app is loaded?

P/D: I have to said that, the launcher is a different application from the game that should be launch.